# Unable to use the Selenium framework (pom.xml), after upgrading Firefox browser to 57.0

Tags: maven, selenium-webdriver, testng

[image]

I am unable to use the Selenium framework (pom.xml), after upgrading Firefox browser to 57.0. Selenium - Oxygen 1

Below is the error:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (Log).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for 
more info.
org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to 
host 
127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:
file\extensions\fxdriver@googlecode.com
```

Note: I am able to run my script with .xml but unable to run same with pom.xml

Refer screenshot

Below is my POM class:

```
  <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.justdial</groupId>
    <artifactId>WebApplicationFramework</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>Evangelist</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.7</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>2.53.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.9.4</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.18.1</version>
            <type>maven-plugin</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>[3.9,)</version>
        </dependency>
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>[3.9,)</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
            <version>[3.9,)</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency><!-- This is required for Selenium -->
            <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
            <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.01</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sourceforge.jexcelapi</groupId>
            <artifactId>jxl</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.xmlbeans</groupId>
            <artifactId>xmlbeans</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    <version>22.0</version>
</dependency>

        <dependency><!--Might have to add mysql-connector-java-5.1.13-bin -->
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.35</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>justdial</groupId>
            <artifactId>web-automation</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>C:/Users/vaibhavsi/.m2/repository/justdial/web-
     automation/1.0.0/web-automation-1.0.0.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <!-- <build> <plugins> <plugin> <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId> 
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId> <configuration> <groups>${group.type}</groups> 
        <properties> <property> <name>listener</name> <value>com.justdial.listener.CustomReporter,com.justdial.listener.CustomListener,com.justdial.listener.TestsListenerAdapter</value> 
        </property> </properties> </configuration> </plugin> </plugins> </build> -->

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.18.1</version>

                <configuration>
                    <suiteXmlFiles>
                        <suiteXmlFile>Intlautomation.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                    </suiteXmlFiles>
                    <systemPropertyVariables>
                        <!-- Paramater execution environment "mvn test -
                             DsuiteFile=smoke.xml 
                            -Denvironment=sandbox" -->
                        <environment>Staging</environment>
                    </systemPropertyVariables>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <filesets>
                        <fileset>

    <directory>src/test/java/org/justdial/log/Screenshots</directory>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/*.*</include>
                            </includes>
                            <followSymlinks>false</followSymlinks>
                        </fileset>
                    </filesets>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <fork>true</fork>
                    <executable>C:/Program 
    Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_144/bin/javac.exe</executable>
                    <compilerVersion>1.8</compilerVersion>
                    <!-- <source>1.7</source> <target>1.7</target> -->
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

    <reporting>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.18.1</version>
            </plugin>

                <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jxr-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5</version>
                </plugin>

             </plugins>
    </reporting>

</project>
```

Adding scripts:

```
package com.justdial.International;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;

import org.justdial.appLib.ApplicationLibrary;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import com.justdial.base.TestBase;
import com.justdial.frame.Email;
import com.justdial.frame.ExcelReadWrite;
import com.justdial.urbanclap.UrbanClap;

public class IntlAutomation extends ApplicationLibrary{
    private static final String String = null;
    ExcelReadWrite exclwrdt=  new ExcelReadWrite();
    Email email = new Email();

    // Create excel sheet
    public IntlAutomation (){
        this.exclwrdt = exclwrdt;

    }
    @Test (priority = 1)
    public void USAutomation() throws InterruptedException, IOException  {
         WebDriver driver = null;
        exclwrdt.createFile();
        TestBase api = new TestBase();
        US_Home us = new US_Home(driver, exclwrdt);

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------  
    exclwrdt.createWorkSheet("Web_US_Home", 0);

/*  us.Proxy_Server("https://us.justdial.com/");
    exclwrdt.writeDataInBold("Proxy Server", "");*/

    //us.closeDriver();
    //exclwrdt.writeDataInBold("Proxy Server closed", "");

    us.jdpagelaunch("https://us.justdial.com/");
    exclwrdt.writeDataInBold("New York City", "");


/*  exclwrdt.writeDataInBold("Restaurants", "");
    us.restaurants ();
    us.enterarea("New st");
    //us.resultpage();

    exclwrdt.writeDataInBold("Doctors", "");
    us.Home_page();
    us.doctors();
    us.enterarea("New st");
    //us.resultpage();


    exclwrdt.writeDataInBold("Hotels", "");
    us.Home_page();
    us.Hotels();
    us.enterarea("New st");
    //us.resultpage();

    exclwrdt.writeDataInBold("Car dealers", "");
    us.Home_page();
    us.Car_Dealers();
    us.enterarea("New st");

    exclwrdt.writeDataInBold("Movies", "");
    us.Home_page();
    us.Movies();
    us.enterarea("New St");*/

    exclwrdt.writeDataInBold("Login", "");
    us.Home_page();
    us.Login();

    //exclwrdt.writeDataInBold("Freelisting", "");
    //us.Freelisting();

    //exclwrdt.writeDataInBold("Testimonials", "");
    //us.Home_page();
    //us.Testimonials(); 

    exclwrdt.writeDataInBold("Details_Page", "");
    us.Home_page();
    us.Details_page();
    us.Details_page_Tabs(); 

    //exclwrdt.writeDataInBold("Feedback", "");
    //us.Home_page();
    //us.Feedback();

    exclwrdt.writeDataInBold("Results Page", "");
    us.Home_page();
    us.resultpage0();
    }




    @Test (priority = 2)
    public void CAAutomation() throws InterruptedException, IOException  {
         WebDriver driver = null;
        exclwrdt.createFile();
        TestBase api = new TestBase();
        US_Home us = new US_Home(driver, exclwrdt); 

        //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        exclwrdt.createWorkSheet("Web_Canada_Home", 0);

        us.Proxy_Server("https://ca.justdial.com/");
        exclwrdt.writeDataInBold("Proxy Server", "");

        //us.closeDriver();
        //exclwrdt.writeDataInBold("Proxy Server closed", "");

        us.jdpagelaunch("https://ca.justdial.com/");
        exclwrdt.writeDataInBold("Toronto", "");


        /*exclwrdt.writeDataInBold("Restaurants", "");
        us.restaurants ();
        us.enterarea("New st");
        //us.resultpage();

        exclwrdt.writeDataInBold("Doctors", "");
        us.Home_page();
        us.doctors();
        us.enterarea("New st");
        //us.resultpage();


        exclwrdt.writeDataInBold("Hotels", "");
        us.Home_page();
        us.Hotels();
        us.enterarea("New st");
        //us.resultpage();

        exclwrdt.writeDataInBold("Car dealers", "");
        us.Home_page();
        us.Car_Dealers();
        us.enterarea("New st");*/

        exclwrdt.writeDataInBold("Movies", "");
        us.Home_page();
        us.Movies();
        us.enterarea("New st");

    /*  exclwrdt.writeDataInBold("Login", "");
        us.Home_page();
        us.Login();

        exclwrdt.writeDataInBold("Freelisting", "");
        us.Freelisting();

        exclwrdt.writeDataInBold("Testimonials", "");
        us.Home_page();
        us.Testimonials();  

        //exclwrdt.writeDataInBold("Details_Page", "");
        //us.Home_page();
        //us.Details_page();
        //us.Details_page_Tabs(); 

        exclwrdt.writeDataInBold("Feedback", "");
        us.Home_page();
        us.Feedback();

        exclwrdt.writeDataInBold("Results Page", "");
        us.Home_page();
    us.resultpage0();*/
        }




//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------  
@AfterTest(alwaysRun=true)

public void executeatlast() throws IOException, MessagingException 
{
    exclwrdt.closeWrite();
    //email.main(null);
        // InternetAddress[] recepients = InternetAddress.parse("testingteam@justdial.com,bharatsharma@justdial.com");
        InternetAddress[] recepients = InternetAddress.parse("vaibhav.singh@justdial.com");
     email.sendMail("vaibhav.singh@justdial.com",recepients, ExcelReadWrite.FileName, exclwrdt.getTabs(),"International Automation Report");

}
}
```

Note : I am working on a framework of selenium library.

Error Logs are as follow:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (Log).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:
    Save changes
1512381676397   DeferredSave.webext.sc.lz4  DEBUG   Save changes
[Child 3944, Chrome_ChildThread] WARNING: pipe error: 109: file z:/build/build/src/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/ipc_channel_win.cc, line 346
[Child 3944, Chrome_ChildThread] WARNING: pipe error: 109: file z:/build/build/src/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/ipc_channel_win.cc, line 346
1512381679408   DeferredSave.addons.json    DEBUG   Write succeeded
1512381679419   DeferredSave.webext.sc.lz4  DEBUG   Save changes
1512381679420   DeferredSave.webext.sc.lz4  DEBUG   Save changes
1512381679712   DeferredSave.webext.sc.lz4  DEBUG   Starting write
1512381679722   DeferredSave.webext.sc.lz4  DEBUG   Write succeeded
1512381680194   addons.xpi  INFO    Mapping fxdriver@googlecode.com to C:\Users\vaibhavsi\AppData\Local\Temp\anonymous2209326214180969524webdriver-profile\extensions\fxdriver@googlecode.com
1512381680194   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Ignoring file entry whose name is not a valid add-on ID: C:\Users\vaibhavsi\AppData\Local\Temp\anonymous2209326214180969524webdriver-profile\extensions\webdriver-staging
1512381680195   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Existing add-on fxdriver@googlecode.com in app-profile
1512381680196   addons.xpi  INFO    Mapping activity-stream@mozilla.org to C:\Users\vaibhavsi\AppData\Local\Mozilla Firefox\browser\features\activity-stream@mozilla.org.xpi
1512381680197   addons.xpi  INFO    Mapping aushelper@mozilla.org to C:\Users\vaibhavsi\AppData\Local\Mozilla Firefox\browser\features\aushelper@mozilla.org.xpi
1512381680197   addons.xpi  INFO    Mapping e10srollout@mozilla.org to C:\Users\vaibhavsi\AppData\Local\Mozilla Firefox\browser\features\e10srollout@mozilla.org.xpi
1512381680197   addons.xpi  INFO    Mapping firefox@getpocket.com to C:\Users\vaibhavsi\AppData\Local\Mozilla Firefox\browser\features\firefox@getpocket.com.xpi
1512381680197   addons.xpi  INFO    Mapping followonsearch@mozilla.com to C:\Users\vaibhavsi\AppData\Local\Mozilla Firefox\browser\features\followonsearch@mozilla.com.xpi
1512381680197   addons.xpi  INFO    Mapping formautofill@mozilla.org to C:\Users\vaibhavsi\AppData\Local\Mozilla Firefox\browser\features\formautofill@mozilla.org.xpi
1512381680197   addons.xpi  INFO    Mapping onboarding@mozilla.org to C:\Users\vaibhavsi\AppData\Local\Mozilla Firefox\browser\features\onboarding@mozilla.org.xpi
1512381680197   addons.xpi  INFO    Mapping screenshots@mozilla.org to C:\Users\vaibhavsi\AppData\Local\Mozilla Firefox\browser\features\screenshots@mozilla.org.xpi
1512381680198   addons.xpi  INFO    Mapping shield-recipe-client@mozilla.org to C:\Users\vaibhavsi\AppData\Local\Mozilla Firefox\browser\features\shield-recipe-client@mozilla.org.xpi
1512381680198   addons.xpi  INFO    Mapping webcompat@mozilla.org to C:\Users\vaibhavsi\AppData\Local\Mozilla Firefox\browser\features\webcompat@mozilla.org.xpi
1512381680200   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Existing add-on activity-stream@mozilla.org in app-system-defaults
1512381680200   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Existing add-on aushelper@mozilla.org in app-system-defaults
1512381680202   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Existing add-on e10srollout@mozilla.org in app-system-defaults
1512381680203   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Existing add-on firefox@getpocket.com in app-system-defaults
1512381680203   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Existing add-on followonsearch@mozilla.com in app-system-defaults
1512381680204   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Existing add-on formautofill@mozilla.org in app-system-defaults
1512381680204   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Existing add-on onboarding@mozilla.org in app-system-defaults
1512381680205   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Existing add-on screenshots@mozilla.org in app-system-defaults
1512381680206   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Existing add-on shield-recipe-client@mozilla.org in app-system-defaults
1512381680207   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Existing add-on webcompat@mozilla.org in app-system-defaults
1512381680208   addons.xpi  INFO    Mapping {972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd} to C:\Users\vaibhavsi\AppData\Local\Mozilla Firefox\browser\extensions\{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}.xpi
1512381680210   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Existing add-on {972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd} in app-global
1512381680211   addons.xpi  DEBUG   getInstallState changed: false, state: {}

    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:113)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.startClient(FirefoxDriver.java:271)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:119)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:216)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:211)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:207)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:120)
    at com.justdial.International.US_Home.<init>(US_Home.java:25)
    at com.justdial.International.IntlAutomation.USAutomation(IntlAutomation.java:34)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:85)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:659)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:845)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1153)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:108)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:771)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:621)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:357)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:352)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:310)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:259)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1199)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1124)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1032)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGExecutor.run(TestNGExecutor.java:295)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGXmlTestSuite.execute(TestNGXmlTestSuite.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGProvider.invoke(TestNGProvider.java:90)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:203)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:155)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:103)
Dec 04, 2017 3:31:42 PM org.openqa.selenium.os.ProcessUtils killWinProcess
WARNING: Process refused to die after 10 seconds, and couldn't taskkill it
java.lang.NullPointerException: Unable to find executable for: taskkill
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:823)
    at org.openqa.selenium.os.UnixProcess.<init>(UnixProcess.java:62)
    at org.openqa.selenium.os.CommandLine.<init>(CommandLine.java:38)
    at org.openqa.selenium.os.WindowsUtils.killPID(WindowsUtils.java:178)
    at org.openqa.selenium.os.ProcessUtils.killWinProcess(ProcessUtils.java:138)
    at org.openqa.selenium.os.ProcessUtils.killProcess(ProcessUtils.java:81)
    at org.openqa.selenium.os.UnixProcess$SeleniumWatchDog.destroyHarder(UnixProcess.java:247)
    at org.openqa.selenium.os.UnixProcess$SeleniumWatchDog.access$200(UnixProcess.java:201)
    at org.openqa.selenium.os.UnixProcess.destroy(UnixProcess.java:125)
    at org.openqa.selenium.os.CommandLine.destroy(CommandLine.java:155)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxBinary.quit(FirefoxBinary.java:246)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.quit(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:194)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver$LazyCommandExecutor.quit(FirefoxDriver.java:364)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.stopClient(FirefoxDriver.java:310)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:122)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:216)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:211)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:207)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:120)
    at com.justdial.International.US_Home.<init>(US_Home.java:25)
    at com.justdial.International.IntlAutomation.USAutomation(IntlAutomation.java:34)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:85)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:659)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:845)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1153)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:108)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:771)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:621)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:357)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:352)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:310)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:259)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1199)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1124)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1032)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGExecutor.run(TestNGExecutor.java:295)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGXmlTestSuite.execute(TestNGXmlTestSuite.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGProvider.invoke(TestNGProvider.java:90)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:203)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:155)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:103)
```

Comment: Error says it all `file\extensions\fxdriver@googlecode.com`, error is stemming out of the extension which you are trying to load probhably through FirefoxProfile.

Comment: What is the solution for the same. Please look into same.

Comment: Update the question with your code block please.

Comment: @VaibhavSingh What is the selenium version? What do you mean by - " I am able to run my script with .xml but unable to run same with pom.xml"?. Where is the screenshot? Also you have a connection error...

Comment: @Grasshopper I mean my scripts are running fine, when I am trying to run as Intlautomation.xml but after configuring same in pom.xml same is not working.

Comment: Added screenshot.

Comment: This is happening after updating my Firefox version/update. Same was working fine earlier.

Comment: @VaibhavSingh Upgrade selenium version.

Comment: @VaibhavSingh Where are you initializing the local variable "driver" in the tests before passing it to US_Home consructor?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: @halfer I am extremely sorry, I was not aware. I have to push these scripts within time lines.

Comment: Hi All, Any update on the same. Please look into same. ASAP.

Answer (score 1):

I can see a couple of issues in your **`pom.xml`**. Can you update them as follows :

- **`poi-ooxml`**

  ```
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
      <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
      <version>3.9</version>
  </dependency>
  ```
- **`poi-ooxml-schemas`**

  ```
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
      <artifactId>poi-ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
      <version>3.9</version>
  </dependency>
  ```

---

### Update :

These errors are harmless and logged because you have configured `Apache Log4j` in one of the modules in this project but not in this module. Hence you see these :

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (Log).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

Your main error is :

```
org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:
```

The reason for this error is Mismatch between **`Selenium Client`** and **`Firefox Web Browser`**. As you are trying to use **`Firefox v57.0`** try to use the recent version of **`Selenium Client`** i.e. **`v3.8.1`** and **`GeckoDriver`** i.e. **`v0.19.1`**

Comment: Have made the changes in pom class. still not working.

Comment: @VaibhavSingh What is the new error you are seeing?

Comment: Same error, I have added new error logs seen in console.

Comment: Have updated the same, after updating to this version i am encountering Issue. Earlier, same was working fine.